# chrome extnaions iframes tabcapture

Tags: google-chrome-extension

hello I've been working on my chrome extension and I tried to use the tabcapture API and in the docs,
it says that this API only works in **Foreground only** I've been trying to start the API in the content script and it didn't work in the end I started the API inside an iframe that was created from the content script and got an Error that tab **capture cannot start** .

I think that is because of the iframe permissions or because I didn't understand the foreground correctly

if some could point me in the right direction ...

Answer (score 0):

Content script of extension don't have permission to access or monitor tabs. Because it was restricted to that tab scope.

But extension background have access to monitor all the tabs. Using

chrome.tab.onupdate.addListener(listener: function)

Ref: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/

If you required details in content script. You can monitor from background and communication to content script.