# chrome.tabCapture unavailable in MV3's new offscreen API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

Our extension uses tabCapture to record the sound of a tab. In MV3, [chrome.tabCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabCapture/) is only available in foreground pages (like popups), which makes the API useless for recording anything in the tab since it can't be kept open.

There's the current hack which opens an extension page in a new Tab while recording, to satisfy both the keep-alive and foreground constraints in the API, but that is less than ideal as it requires tabs pop-in and pop-out of existence without user interaction so it makes for a terrible user experience.

Then there's the new [chrome.offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) API which had this capturing use case as one of its main highlighted use cases in the initial draft request by Devlin Cronin [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1b-I-vXq2h7OFFmus78jZXIWcKilKJLKLeGplnY9wt7k/edit#). Now, the offscreen API is enabled in **109 beta** ready to be deployed in production on *Jan 10th 2023* and this use case appears ignored. chrome.tabCapture is **not** exposed to the offscreen document.

In the extension service worker:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.offscreen.hasDocument().then(function(has) {
        if (!has) {
            chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
                justification: 'record audio',
                reasons: [chrome.offscreen.Reason.USER_MEDIA],
                url: chrome.runtime.getURL('record.html'),
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In the offscreen document's JS script:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(chrome.tabCapture); // **this is always undefined**
    });
});
```

So now the question. Is there another way to record the current tab audio that isn't listed above? Not talking about recording the user's mic with getUserMedia and not involving desktopCapture which brings up the nasty popup. The ideal solution would still involve tabCapture. But how?

Comment: Add an iframe to the web page with src pointing to a page exposed via `web_accessible_resources`. Inside this iframe you'll have an extension environment with full access to all API.

Comment: @wOxxOm this is not working. First, tabCapture can't be started from the iframe with "Error starting tab capture". I also see a report [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68739084/chrome-extnaions-iframes-tabcapture) claiming the same thing. Secondly, I can get a streamId from the iframe using chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId, pass the string to the content script and get the stream from there using getUserMedia. But, the moment getUserMedia gets invoked, the tab is muted and there is no way around it, not even with connecting the source to the speaker destination using AudioContext

Comment: It could be a bug in Chrome, I guess. See [this thread](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/issues/627) for workarounds.

Comment: @wOxxOm in support of my previous comment, I've created a minimal working demo extension which reproduces the bug, if you could confirm you get the same behaviour https://github.com/Deewde/getUserMedia-mutes-the-tab